# Windows phone 8.1 tiles issues

Tags: windows-phone-8, tiles, windows-phone-8.1

I am currently working on an application that was developed using windows phone 8.0 sdk and and i targeted it to work with Wp8.1 SDK. Everything is working fine, apart from the issue with tiles. For some reason, it is taking the WMAAppmanifest settings into consideration instead of the Package.appxmanifest file.

here's my Application tag in the Package.appxmanifest file,

```
<Applications>
    <Application Id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" Executable="AGHost.exe" EntryPoint="/Views/SplashScreen.xaml">
      <m3:VisualElements DisplayName="SampleUI" Square150x150Logo="Assets\SquareTile150x150.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Logo.png" Description="SyncUI" ForegroundText="light" BackgroundColor="#464646">
        <m3:DefaultTile Square71x71Logo="Assets\SquareTile71x71.png">
        </m3:DefaultTile>
        <m3:SplashScreen Image="Assets\Splashscreen.png" />
      </m3:VisualElements>
      <Extensions>
        <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="ScheduleSync.TimerTriggerTask">
          <BackgroundTasks>
            <Task Type="systemEvent" />
            <Task Type="timer" />
          </BackgroundTasks>
        </Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
```

The tile doesn't seem to change irrespective of what i change the image to be.

Am i looking at the right place? Is there some other place where i need to change the tiles ?

Comment: Isn't this related to the Notification Service you're using? If it's MPN - the WMAppManifest info is used, if it's WNS - the info in the package.appxmanifest file is used. Which one are you using? (You can see by opening the WMAppManifest file). I could be wrong though.

Comment: @yasen, i dont think it is related to Notification Service. MPNS and WNS are related to that....but not with respect to my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the tile in the WMAppmanifest instead of the Packageappxmanifest.

Here's the sample,

```
<Tokens>
      <PrimaryToken TokenID="Token1" TaskName="_default">
        <TemplateType5>
          <BackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Images\Cloud_WP8_71x71.png</BackgroundImageURI>
          <Count>0</Count>
          <Title>Sample Cloud</Title>
        </TemplateType5>
      </PrimaryToken>
    </Tokens>
```

Answer (score 0):

Double Click on the Package.appxmanifest in the Solution Explorer of your project. It will load up a GUI for updating the App manifest rather than using the xml versions.

In the GUI representation there will be a 'Visual Assets' Tab at the top which will let you set each of the different tiles.

Here is a link to a video of how to use the Package.appmanifest file. It also talks about hwo to set the tiles of the app. http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-8-Working-with-the-package-appxmanifest

Comment: I dont see the the Visual Assets tab. i am assuming the reason to be the upgrade from 8.0 to 8.1

Comment: Sorry I was looking at a Window Store 8.1 App. What tabs do you have?

Comment: Application, Capabilities, Declarations, Packaging

Comment: In WP8 the Tile Images are under Application UI, I would suspect that it would be something similar.

Comment: Try the Application Tab. In WP8, they are at the very bottom. Let me know if you find them

Comment: I think you may be in the wrong file. I found a video of how to change the tiles of a WP8.1 application, and his package.appmanifest GUI layout is different to what you are saying. I've linked the video into my answer